# Manual Transactions with Seam POJO

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, seam

What is best practice for using Database Transactions with Seam when not using EJBs - ie. when deploying Seam as a WAR?

By default Seam JavaBeans support Transactions. I can annotate a method with @Transactional and that will ensure that a transaction is required. Or I can use @Transactional(NEVER) or @Transactional(MANDATORY). What I can't find out how to do is to create my own Transaction, set a timeout, begin and then commit/rollback.

I have tried using:

```
UserTransaction utx = Transaction.instance();
utx.setTransactionTimeout(2000);
utx.begin();
```

But it is either ignored if a Transaction is already in progress or returns a javax.transaction.NotSupportedException if I annotate the method with @Transactional(NEVER)

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: give the fully qualified name of @Transactional

Comment: org.jboss.seam.annotations.Transactional

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know, Transaction Management is a cross-cutting concern. So it is not a good idea your code scattered about in modules where those concerns are not their primary concern.

If you are using a JTA UserTransaction in a non-EJB environment, so JTA is avaliable (Apache Tomcat does not support JTA).

**1° rule**

> Seam transaction management **is enabled by default** for all JSF requests (Seam 2.0+).

I think *Seam transaction management* sounds better as **Transactions managed by Seam**. It means Seam takes cares, behind the scenes, of calling begin and commit. Seam plays the role of Transaction manager by using a Seam Transaction Manager

**1° scenario**: POJO + JTA avaliable (Apache Tomcat does not support JTA)

Transaction Manager used by Seam: org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTtransaction

Enabled by default in non-EJB environment (war) when JTA available (JBoss support JTA)

If you are using JPA EntityManager or Hibernate Session, you need to register them to allows Seam manage transaction boundaries

See [9.3. Seam-managed persistence contexts](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts) how to set up a Seam managed persistence context (Injected by using @In)

Then inject a EntityManager (EntityManager) or Session (Hibernate) by using @In (scoped to ScopeType.CONVERSATION)

```
@Name("businessService")
public class BusinessServiceImpl implementes BusinessService {

    @In
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        // You do not need to call entityManager().getTransaction().begin();
        // because Seam Transaction Manager takes care of it
        // By using proxies
        // Therefore, if you call entityManager().getTransaction().begin()
        // You will get IllegalStateException

        // Some EntityManager operations persist, find etc

        // You do not need to call entityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        // because Seam Transaction Manager takes care of it
        // By using proxies
    }

}
```

Behind the scenes, Seam Transaction Manager enlist the EntityManager (JPA) or Session (Hibernate) in the active JTA UserTransaction, by calling [joinTransaction](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#joinTransaction()) method

**2° scenario**: POJO + RESOURCE_LOCAL (Either Hibernate or JPA) Transaction

Transaction Manager used by Seam (JPA): org.jboss.seam.transaction.EntityTransaction

Transaction Manager used by Seam (Hibernate): org.jboss.seam.transaction.HibernateTransaction

See [9.3. Seam-managed persistence contexts](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts) how to set up a Seam managed persistence context (Injected by using @In)

Behind the scenes, Seam Transaction Manager takes care of calling begin and commit in the underlying technology by using proxies

**3° scenario**: EJB

Transaction Manager used by Seam : org.jboss.seam.transaction.CMTTransaction

Enabled by default in EJB environment. Take care, in that case, Seam does not control container-managed transaction.

regards,

Answer (score 6):

The way I'm currently working is like this:

```
//don't use @Transactional annotation
public void doStuff() {
  UserTransaction userTx = (UserTransaction) org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance("org.jboss.seam.transaction.transaction");
  userTx.setTransactionTimeout(10 * 60);  //set timeout to 60 * 10 = 600 secs = 10 mins
  userTx.begin();

  /*If entity manager is created before the transaction is started (ie. via Injection) then it must join the transaction */
  entityManager.joinTransaction();

  //do stuff    

  entityManager.persist(user);
  entityManager.flush();   //logs will show an insert at this point

  userTx.commit();   //or rollback()
}
```

But if a Transaction is already in progress and you want to join it then you use the userTx.isActive() etc

Comment: Excellent man!!! I could use this to avoid "Transaction is not active" exception.